# use response write to make a link

Tags: asp-classic

I have a urlcolumn and a title column and i want the link to be automatically made in asp

```
 <td><%response.write(<a href="rs.fields.item("urlcolumn")target=_"blank">rs.fields.item("titlecolumn")</a>)%></td>
```

Comment: You need to correct your `target` link, it should be `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the minimum, you will need to quote the output value for Response.Write to work, i.e.

```
<td><%Response.Write("<a href='" + rs.fields.item("urlcolumn") + "' target='_blank'>" + rs.fields.item("titlecolumn") + "</a>")%></td>
```

EDIT (updated my code sample).

EDIT #2 - Make sure to clean any input going into these links.  Creating links this way makes you very vulnerable to a XSS attack (especially since the href attribute can actually execute Javascript).

Answer (score 1):

You could do what you are trying by string concatenation:

<%= Response.Write("<a href=\"" + rs.fields.item("urlcolumn") + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + rs.fields.item("titlecolumn") + "</a>") %>

However, you might be better served using an [asp:HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx) control.

Comment: No joke, that's why I generally try to use controls, rather than inlining everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><%response.write("<a href=""" & rs.fields.item("urlcolumn") & """ target=""_blank"">" & rs.fields.item("titlecolumn") & "</a>")%></td>
```